# Using the Strong Law of Large Numbers to find a constant, c.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

Let $X_1, X_2...$ be independent and identically distributed with mean 4 and variance 20. Set $S_n = X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_n$ and $V_n = X_1^2 + X_2^2 + … + X_n^2$. Use the Strong Law of Large Numbers to find a constant $c$ such that $P\left(\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{S_n}{V_n} = c\right) = 1$. I've tried to find the expected value of $\frac{S_n}{V_n}$ as I believe that should be the answer, which I keep computing, incorrectly, as $\frac{1}{104}$. What should I be doing here instead?

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\frac{S_{n}}{V_n}=\frac{S_n/n}{V_{n}/n}\to\frac{EX_{1}}{EX_{1}^2}
$$
a.s. as $n\to \infty$ by the SLLN and limit laws. You should able to compute $EX_{1}^2$ from the givens.

Comment: Thank you! This was a huge help!